# Resizing a maximized window from the command line

Tags: window-management, wmctrl, xdotool

The following script fails to resize an already maximized window:

```
wmctrl -i -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
xdotool windowunmap --sync
xdotool windowmap   --sync
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,300,168,740,470
```

I am pretty sure the culprit is in the middle two lines, which I am meaning to apply to the currently active window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the `-i` option in the first wmctrl cmd is causing trouble.
Try this:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,300,168,740,470
```

Comment: It seems as if, when a window is maximized, that `wmctrl` cannot resize same until such time as the `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz` is invoked.