# Script to maximize an app when it starts

Tags: bash, scripting, application, maximize

I am aware that this question is duplicated:
[How to set window size and location of an application on screen via command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43106/how-to-set-window-size-and-location-of-an-application-on-screen-via-command-line/283528#283528)
[Resizing a maximized window from the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159684/resizing-a-maximized-window-from-the-command-line)

I was able to solve my question with the first link. But I am struggling to learn Bash language and I would like to know what is going wrong with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

xfce4-settings-manager & sleep 0.1
xwininfo -name "xfce4-settings-manager" | grep xwininfo: | awk {'printf$4'}
wmctrl -i -r $1 -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz &
```

After running the script I check "xwininfo" takes another ID Value of the app. I don't understand why. Can someone give me a hand with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your second line runs xwininfo but doesn't save the output anywhere -- it'll display to your screen. The wmctrl line uses the $1 parameter to the script; are you passing something in, or do you expect the xwininfo command to be providing that input to wmctrl?

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks for replying. I want the result of the second line is retrieved by $1 of the third line. How could I do that? I tried to define a variable for the second line ($WID, for instance) and retrieve in the third line, but It did not work. Can you tell me how I could do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The tool you're looking for is [Devil's Pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil's_Pie_(software)) (either version 1 and version 2, note that they use completely different configuration languages). There are a number of examples on this site, e.g. [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344389/make-program-start-on-second-virtual-desktop-xfce/344515#344515) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320592/remember-on-which-desktop-window-belongs/320645#320645) [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281622/how-to-start-an-app-on-specific-head/281773#281773) [4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139152/configure-toggleshowdesktop-in-openbox-to-only-act-on-specified-layer/139928#139928).

The problem with your script has already been identified by [Jeff Schaller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117549/jeff-schaller) in a comment: the line that extracts the output from `xwininfo` doesn't plug into the line that calls `wmctrl`. To use the output of a command in a script, use a [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution).

```
windowid=$(xwininfo -name "xfce4-settings-manager" | awk '$1 == "xwininfo:" {printf $4}')
wmctrl -i -r "$windowid" -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz &
```

I used an intermediate variable to keep the line from becoming unreadably long, but you can do it all inline:

```
wmctrl -i -r "$(xwininfo -name "xfce4-settings-manager" | awk '$1 == "xwininfo:" {printf $4}')" -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz &
```

I also combined the grep and awk invocations, I find it simpler to use a single tool here.

You don't need to use `xwininfo` to find the window ID: `wmctrl` can do it, just pass it the window name.

```
wmctrl -r "xfce4-settings-manager" -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz &
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked with "Devil's Pie" app, but it is still not working with the script. It happens the same as I explained in the first message: xwininfo takes another value of the window. I will explained with an example in a new message (look at the example below).

Answer (score 1):

Since you want:

> the result of the second line is retrieved by $1 of the third line

you could:

```
#!/bin/bash

xfce4-settings-manager & sleep 0.1
wid=$(xwininfo -name "xfce4-settings-manager" | grep xwininfo: | awk {'printf$4'})
wmctrl -i -r "$wid" -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz &
```

though if I could suggest another version (untested, as I'm not in front of an X display):

```
#!/bin/bash

xfce4-settings-manager & 
while ! pgrep xfce4-settings-manager > /dev/null
do
  :
done
wid=$(xwininfo -name "xfce4-settings-manager" | awk '/xwininfo:/ { print $4 }')
wmctrl -i -r "$wid" -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

Changes:

- I'm not sure that wmctrl has to be put in the background, so I removed that `&`
- I combined the awk and grep, because awk can "grep"
- I changed the `sleep 0.1`, which assumes that `xfce4-settings-manager` starts in that amount of time, into a loop that asks `pgrep` to look for the process instead

Comment: Thanks. It worked with "Devil's Pie", but it is still not working with the script. It happens the same as I mentioned earlier. I will try to explain with an example below)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying. I tried to do what @Gilles and @Jeff explained on the above comments, but the script does not work. It has the same problem that I mentioned in my first message.

Let me explain what is happening (line by line):

1. The script starts "xfce4-settings-manager"

   > USER@PC:~$ xfce4-settings-manager & sleep 0.1 ;

> [3] 9825

2. It requires the value of the "xfce4-settings-manager" window. In this example, I only want the output result. In the script I wrote it as Gilles and Jeff told me.

   > USER@PC:~$ xwininfo -name "xfce4-settings-manager" | awk '$1 == "xwininfo:" {printf $4}'
   >   0x5400001
3. I include the window value in the last command (0x5400001), but the window does not maximize.

   > USER@PC:~$ wmctrl -i -r 0x5400001 -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz

> [4] 9852

4. I run "xwininfo" command and select the "xfce4-settings-manager" window and this is its result:

   > USER@PC:~$ xwininfo

> xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
>            would like information by clicking the
>            mouse in that window.
>
> xwininfo: Window id: 0x5800003 "Settings"
>
> Absolute upper-left X:  343
>
> Absolute upper-left Y:  286
>
> Relative upper-left X:  5
>
> Relative upper-left Y:  19
>
> Width: 680
>
> Height: 195
>
> Depth: 24
>
> Visual: 0x20
>
> Visual Class: TrueColor
>
> Border width: 0
>
> Class: InputOutput
>
> Colormap: 0x22 (installed)
>
> Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
>
> Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
>
> Backing Store State: NotUseful
>
> Save Under State: no
>
> Map State: IsViewable
>
> Override Redirect State: no
>
> Corners:  +343+286  -343+286  -343-287  +343-287
>
> -geometry 680x195+338+267
>
> [2]   Done                    xfce4-settings-manager
>
> [4]+  Done                    wmctrl -i -r 0x5400001 -b 
>   add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz

The window value of "xfce4-settings-manager" is different depending of retrieving the value from the command line or from selecting the window with the cursor (0x5400001 & 0x5800003).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`evince` has window titles equal to the PDF file titles, and no word evince in it... so another aproach to try is to wait for a while (`sleep 0.4` for evince was enough), and then just maximize the last window in the `wmctrl -l` list (i.e., last added window) like this:

```
evince file.pdf & sleep 0.4; wmctrl -i -r "$(wmctrl -l | tail -1 | fgrep -o '^\S+')" -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

This works with ANY app, though you must be sure that you have waited enough for it to be brought up to `wmctrl`